# Tensorflow Simple Character Regconition: Code producing Nan or 0 only;

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I have tried to learn to use Tensorflow. After listening to the tensorflow demonstration, I am trying using tensorflow to recognize characters with the 1 layer nerual network model (the same model demonstrated in the tensorflow talk given by Martin Görner). My dataset are just 773 images of 62 characters including 0 to 9, A to Z and a to z.

What I did was reducing the size of every image to 32 * 32 (1024 pixels each image), and then I flattened it just like the first example in the talk. and use the following code to estimate weights for my model:

My dataset:
**train** is my training image of shape (773,1024): 773 images, and 32*32 flattened to 1024 pixels;
**label_train_m** is a 'matrix' or 2D array of shape (773, 62), 773 images, and 62 characters (0 to 9, A to Z and a to z) of the following form:

```
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 1.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   ..., 
   [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  1.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  1.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

obviously, it is just like a dummy matrix: for example, the corresponding value of the first row (or first image in a flattened form) is 0, then 1 is put in that position in the matrix to indicate this is a 0.

That is pretty much the set up of my dataset.
In terms of the model, it is just very straight forward matrix operations:
L = X.W + b as shown in the talk; L is the probabilities matrix; X is the pixel value matrix, W is the weight matrix, b is bias or constant which will be the same for any image.

In tensorflow, my code is:

```
XX = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [773, 32 * 32])
Y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [773,62]) # 62 characters;
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([32*32, 62]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([62]))

Y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(XX, W) + b)
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_mean(Y_ * tf.log(Y)) * 1000.0
train_step = 
tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0005).minimize(cross_entropy)
# init
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(0,1000):
        ce, w, bias, y = sess.run([cross_entropy, W, b, Y], feed_dict={XX: 
        train, Y_:label_train_m})
```

It doesn't not give any error, I suppose I got the dimension right. But the result from codes above gives me only 0 for all entries in bias, w, y and cross_entropy.

If I add train_step into iteration like the follow:

```
    for i in range(0,1000):
    ce, tr, w, bias, y = sess.run([cross_entropy, train_step, W, b, Y], 
    feed_dict={XX: train, Y_:label_train_m})
```

I only obtain nan for all entries in bias, w, y and cross_entropy.

I am wondering what has gone wrong, considering most of the codes are just copied down from the demo with some slight modification to change to dimension.

Comment: I think you should try initializing your weights and bias to something different from 0. Simple math should show you that with all the weights and bias set to 0 cross entropy goes to + infinity, although I don't know if this bothers tensorflow...

Comment: @ gionni  I have tried your suggestion, but the result is all Nan. it is rather strange to me.

Comment: The cross entropy function seems to be incorrect, it should first sum over the columns and then average over the rows of the resulting vector, like this: `cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))`. This line is from [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners)

Comment: Also, the first part of the code returns 0 because you are not actually training the net if you don't call `train_step` at each iteration

Comment: + gionni  oh thank you for taking a look for me! very much appreciate it. yeah, I add the train step back. I broke down the whole thing, and apparently, the corss_entropy seems to be getting some negative numbers that broke the whole thing. I will check tomorrow for remedy and will take a look at the link you provided. Thank you so much for helping out!

Comment: You are welcome  ;)

Comment: @gionni is that working after fixing of cross entropy?